# how do refs notify its watches in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Comparing the source code of `clojure.lang.Ref` and `clojure.lang.Atom`, I see that they both inherit from `clojure.lang.ARef`.

In `clojure.lang.ARef` there is a function `notifyWatches` which lets all the watch function know that a change has been made.

the `swap!` and `reset!` functions in `clojure.lang.Atom` calls `notifyWatches` in its implementation.

eg.

```
public Object swap(IFn f) {
for(; ;)
    {
    Object v = deref();
    Object newv = f.invoke(v);
    validate(newv);
    if(state.compareAndSet(v, newv))
        {
        notifyWatches(v, newv);
        return newv;
        }
    }
 }
```

However, when I do a search for `notifyWatches` in `clojure.lang.Ref`, it comes up with nothing. The `alter` function looks like this.

```
public Object alter(IFn fn, ISeq args) {
   LockingTransaction t = LockingTransaction.getEx();
   return t.doSet(this, fn.applyTo(RT.cons(t.doGet(this), args)));
}
```

How do all the watch functions of a ref get notified if none of the methods are calling notifyWatches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `notifyWatches` you are looking for occurs in the `run` method of the `LockingTransaction` class.

Changes to refs happen in transactions.  Note that the call to the `doSet` method of `LockingTransaction` is passed `this` (a reference to the Ref). The change that *will be* applied within the transaction is established by the `doSet` method  but that change is effected within the `run` method of `LockingTransaction`. When the transaction is run successfully `notifyWatches` is called using the reference to the Ref recorded by `doSet`.

Answer (score 2):

[clojure.lang.Ref](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Ref.java#L19) extends [clojure.lang.ARef](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ARef.java#L87) which has [the watches](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ARef.java#L19) and provides the notifyWatches method